Combine classes which are different only in async/sync method calls
I want to remove the code duplication, I have a base abstract class A defined in a separate assembly and derived classes B, C (each in a separate assembly), which are different only by calling a sync or async versions of methods. I want to move all the logic to the base class to remove code duplication. I've tried adding virtual methods to the base class for sync and async versions (Evaluate and EvaluateAsync), but it is not the best choice as they will be publically visible and will confuse the customers when to call any of them.
My attempts:
public virtual Task<object?> EvaluateAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<object?>(null);
}

public virtual object? Evaluate()
{
    return null;
}

With this both methods will be available in sync and async assemblies. Is any way to solve it?

I'd say choose one path and stick to it. Sync or Async. If your core functionality is sync in nature, you may lean to sync, if it's async in nature (I/O for example) you may gravitate towards async ...

Sync and async APIs have fundamentally different semantics and signatures - and both "sync over async" and "async over sync" (the "free" workarounds) are anti-patterns; there is no free way of providing a dual API, and duplication like shown is common. I would suggest adding a CancellationToken cancellationToken = default parameter to EvaluateAsync, though. (there's also no such thing as a sync or async assembly, but yes: individual callers might be sync or async)

I might also suggest have a static readonly Task<object?> DefaultResult = Task.FromResult<object?>(null); so you can do return DefaultResult; to avoid allocating a task each time, but if it is likely to be an override in all real cases... perhaps consider making them abstract instead, and lose the default implementation?

^^ If you must provide both versions, I second Marc's remark that you probably have to accept a significant amount of duplication and advise against "pretend" versions that just somehow utilize the respective other version while actually implementing only one.

Thank you guys for your concerns, It's really looks like the code duplication is the only solution. But it's very annoying to make the same changes in both classes. Async assembly is really async. I faced with this issue when contributed to NCalc library on github and tried to find a way to overcome code duplication

What you're asking is anti-pattern and non-logic.
Sync and Async programming use different semantic because they do stuff in different way.
That said, you could achieve what you're asking as follows.

    public class A
    {
        public async Task<object> _DoSomething()
        {
            // Some long elaboration
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public object DoSomething()
        {
            Task<object> T = Task.Run(_DoSomething);
            T.Wait();

            return T.Result;
        }
    }

    public class C : A
    {
        public async Task<object> DoSomething()
        {
            return await _DoSomething();
        }
    }

Let me point out that is not a good practice. now B.DoSomething() and A.DoSomething() have the same signature, but B.DoSomething() will act as blocking method (freezing everything for 1 second) while C.DoSomething() will not. This isn't good imho. As far as i can see, Microsoft libraries as third party libraries do provide different methods when those ones can be both sync and async. System.Data.SQLite.Linq, for example, which is a SQLite developed library to interface c# and sqlite, does provide both sync and async version of the same methods, allowing developers to pick the desired one, so you are able to find an Open() method as well as an OpenAsync() method, a CreateCommand() method as well as a CreateCommadAsync() method, and so on. Keep sync and async logic on theyr own, name them differently, do not mix them, that's not a good idea generically speaking.

Thank you, but in my case they're a standalone packages (with sync and async implementation), you can check NCalc library on github, there is AsyncBuiltInFunctionHelper and BuiltInFunctionHelper, the only difference is one is calling async methods inside

I know, but we're speaking about more unique than rare cases. Anyway, that's far as i can help you based on my experience

Very hard to pull off and this is a really simple example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bxt0X4 - but it's an idea. Yet its feasability has many many "if"s.
